# Javascript snippets autoload in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How to add JavaScript snippets to Google chrome  so they are loaded automatically when Google chrome starts

Comment: http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts

Comment: What type of "snippets" are we talking about here?

Comment: for example a snippet to grab all the colors in web page http://bgrins.github.io/devtools-snippets/#allcolors

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Tampermonkey Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en)